# Change Value on a Cells if 2 criteria is met

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code that works to add numbers on level columns. For example in Sheet1, I have this table:

| Name | Level |
| --- | --- |
| Ariana | Level 1 |
| Brian | Level 2 |

When the run button is clicked, vba code would copy the data and changes the level to Level () + 1. But, I need to add additional criteria like this:

- Only add the number for level 1 until 3
- Don't do any changes to level 4

Note: level would only be level 1 - 4

```
Function GetTheLastRow(sheetName As String) As Long
    'Function untuk mendapatkan row terakhir dalam sheet
    Dim sheetTarget As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set sheetTarget = wb.Sheets("Existing")
    lastRow = sheetTarget.Cells(sheetTarget.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    GetTheLastRow = lastRow
End Function
Sub UpDateLevel()
    With Sheets("Existing").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
            On Error Resume Next
                Dim cel As Range
                    For Each cel In Intersect(.Columns(12).SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible).SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeConstants).EntireRow, _
                                              .Columns(13).SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeConstants))
                        With cel.Offset(, 2)
                            .Value = Split(.Value, " ")(0) & " " & Split(.Value, " ")(1) & " " & Split(.Value, " ")(2) & " " & Split(.Value, " ")(3) + 1
                        End With
                    Next
        End With
    End With
```

This is my current code that works perfectly fine. I hope it make sense thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add a check on the last value

```
                    With cel.Offset(, 2)
                        If Split(.Value, " ")(3) < 4 Then
                            .Value = Split(.Value, " ")(0) & " " & Split(.Value, " ")(1) & " " & Split(.Value, " ")(2) & " " & Split(.Value, " ")(3) + 1
                        End If
                    End With
```

which you can also simplify as follows

```
                    With cel.Offset(, 2)
                        Dim vals As Variant
                            vals = Split(.Value, " ")
                            If vals(3) < 4 Then
                                .Value = vals(0) & " " & vals(1) & " " & vals(2) & " " & vals(3) + 1
                            End If
                    End With
```

Answer (score 1):

- `Join` is the opposite function of `Split` in VBA, simplifying the code.
- ***Note:*** According to your code, it seems you're searching for the addition at 4th part of the `level`, rather than the second part as shown in the sample data.

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Split function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vblr6.chm1008907)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [Join function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/join-function?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vblr6.chm1008915)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

```vb
    With cel.Offset(, 2)
        Dim aVal As Variant
        aVal = Split(.Value, " ")
        ' validate the quantity of items in aVal
        ' to avoid error on aVal(3)
        If UBound(aVal) > 2 Then
            ' skip Level 4
            If aVal(3) < 4 Then
                aVal(3) = aVal(3) + 1
                ' Update cell
                .Value = Join(aVal)
            End If
        End If
    End With
```